# How to get the address of the image which is inside the DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have 2 div elements in the html and then the javascript to change their innerHTML to display two images.

But if I want to get their address how to I do it? Currently my methods always return "undefined". Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id ="demo5"
style="
  top: 45px;
  left: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: show;">
</div>


 <div id ="demo6"
 style="
  top: 45px;
  left: 55px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: show;">
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
  var hand = [1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4,5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,6.1,6.2,6.3,6.4,7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,8.1,8.2,8.3,8.4,9.1,9.2,9.3,9.4,10.1,10.2,10.3,10.4,11.1,11.2,11.3,11.4,12.1,12.2,12.3,12.4,13.1,13.2,13.3,13.4]


  a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52)
  b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52)
  do {b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52)}
  while (b==a)


  var address1 = hand[a] + ".jpg"
  var address2 = hand[b] + ".jpg"


  var path = path || 'http://111.com/'; 
  document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = '<img src="' + path + address5 + '" >'; ;
  document.getElementById("demo6").innerHTML = '<img src="' + path + address6 + '" alt = "">';

  function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo5").src
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

}

Comment: I have got the answer  the code I used was getElementById('demo5').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src.split("/").pop().split(".")[0]

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the standard drag and drop code you are using.

```
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

You can use the setData property to attach a particular data to a drag event. You can get that data by getData() function at the drop.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I actually wanted to get the address of the img which is inside the div, I have changed the question to make it easier to read.

Comment: @jindsay You can pass the address of the image in the setData function and receive it in the getData function. *ev.dataTransfer.setData("address", address1);*